# Save multiple inputs incremented

Tags: php, html, laravel, eloquent

I have inputs in for loop incremented by one:

```
<input type="number" name="device_id_1">
<input type="number" name="device_id_2">
...
<input type="number" name="name_1">
<input type="number" name="name_2">
```

I pass the data with ajax to the controller:

```
dd( $request->all());
//dd will return the data like:

"device_id_1" => "100"
"name_1" => "Some Name"
"device_id_2" => "200"
"name_2" => "Other type"
....
```

I have problems saving each **device_id_X** and the rest of them, how should i save the data in the **foreach** loop any ideas?

My current foreach  loop not working of course:

```
       foreach ($devices as $index => $deviceId) {
            $devicesS[] = Device::create([
                'device_id' => $deviceId,
                'name' => $request->name_[$index],
                .....
            ]);
        }
```

Comment: I would use `<input type="number" name="device_id[]">`

Comment: that would return an error on dd already tried

Answer (score 0):

You could have:

```
<input type="hidden" name="items[]">
<input type="number" name="device_id_1">
<input type="number" name="name_1">
...
<input type="hidden" name="items[]">
<input type="number" name="device_id_2">
<input type="number" name="name_2">
```

That would result in the following:

```
foreach ($request->items as $index => $item) {
    $devices[] = [
        'device_id' => $request->get('device_id_'. $index + 1),
        'name' => $request->get('name_'. $index + 1)
    ];
}

Device::insert($devices);
```